# Multiple update replaces to get the code looking correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is my slightly grotty code that works.

```
update P_INVENTORY_MOVEMENTS set qty = REPLACE(qty,' ','')
update P_INVENTORY_MOVEMENTS set qty = REPLACE(qty,'^','')
UPDATE P_INVENTORY_MOVEMENTS SET qty = replace(replace(qty,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
UPDATE P_Inventory_movements SET QTY = '0.00' where isnumeric (qty)<>1
```

It removes whitespace, then hats, then newlines and carriage returns, and then finally for any values left, sets it to 0.00

I think this may be quite poorly written, and I wondered if anyone can see a better way of doing it. Would the best way be to use a larger nested replace or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: What version of sql server are you running?

Comment: If you are using sql server 2012 you should be using [`Try_Cast()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(qty, ' ', ''), '^', ''), Char(13), ''), Char(10), '') new_qty,
                qty
         FROM   P_INVENTORY_MOVEMENTS
         WHERE  qty LIKE '% %'
                 OR qty LIKE '%^%'
                 OR qty LIKE '%' + Char(13) + '%'
                 OR qty LIKE '%' + Char(10) + '%'
                 OR qty LIKE '%[^0-9.]%')
UPDATE cte
SET    QTY = CASE
               WHEN new_qty LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' THEN '0.00' else new_qty
             END
```

Better to alter the `datatype` of `QTY` to `Numeric` to avoid inserting bad data in future

Comment: should the where clause be `qty like ... ` instead?

Comment: The original updates don't turn strings with invalid characters to `''`, it just removes those invalid characters.

Comment: This won't handle cases where qty has more than one of: spaces, hats, /r /n)

Comment: @Prdp Yes sorry to be difficult but it seems to only be able to do one of the changes, not all of them, for example if I have /r or /n it won't remove hat as well

Comment: `like '%[^0-9]%'` matches '.', so 0.00 matches `like '%[^0-9]%'`, add '.' to the like as `like '%[^0-9.]%'`

Comment: @SqlZim - updated.. not sure about your last comment

Comment: @Pdrp I'm saying your like needs to include a period as a valid character. `'%[^0-9.]%' `

Comment: @Pdrp if qty = '1.0 0' your update would turn it to '0.00' http://rextester.com/USX3844

Comment: I would also allow for negative values '%[^0-9.-]%'

Comment: Shouldn't your case include `else new_qty` before `end`? -- otherwise turning the good values into null.

Comment: @Prdp `OR qty LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'` covers all of the other cases, you can reduce your `where` down to `where qty like '%[^0-9.]%'` http://rextester.com/TYNT6142 -- and I would still change it to include negative values by using `where qty like '%[^0-9.-]%'`

Answer (score 2):

Compute replacement in CROSS APPLY and update with CASE

```
   UPDATE P_Inventory_movements 
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT qtyr = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(qty
                        ,' ',''),CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),''),'^','') 
                 ) x
    SET QTY = CASE isnumeric(qtyr) WHEN 1 THEN qtyr ELSE '0.00' END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could nest the replace statements, and use just 2 update statements instead of 4:

```
UPDATE P_Inventory_movements 
SET QTY =   REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(qty,' ','')
                    ,CHAR(13),'')
                ,CHAR(10),'')
            ,'^','')

UPDATE P_Inventory_movements 
SET QTY = '0.00' 
WHERE isnumeric (qty)<>1
```

Comment: Yeah, well, the second update statement is only a well formatted version of the update statement in the question, I didn't change it

Answer (score 1):

### If:

- this is sql server 2012+ for [`try_cast()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) and [`try_parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)
- I don't have access to CLR (e.g. the regex in [**SQL#**](http://www.sqlsharp.com/))
- I don't want to use a UDF to strip out more unwanted characters
- the destination and usage would be `decimal(9,2)`
- I am really sure this value should be `qty` despite any formatting issues

**Then** I would use this to try and deal with dirty data:

```
update p_inventory_movements set 
  qty = replace(replace(replace(replace(
           qty
          ,char(13),'')
          ,char(10),'')
          ,' ','')
          ,'^','')
  where qty like '%[^0-9.-]%';

update p_inventory_movements set 
  qty = coalesce(
     try_parse(updqty as decimal(9,2))
    ,try_parse(updqty as float)
    ,try_parse(updqty as money))
    ,'0.00'
    )
  where try_cast(qty as decimal(9,2)) is null;
```

Testing various bad input with different functions: http://rextester.com/KHNE65079